# terraform syntax question for name parameter I supppose

Tags: terraform

I use this sample tempate for docker provider taken from Terraform's site:

```
resource "docker_container" "foo" {
image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
name  = "foo"
 }

 resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
 name = "ubuntu:latest"
}
```

So my question is: what's the difference between name = "foo" and "foo" in the resource definition because in the docs they say that "docker_container" is Type of the resource and "foo" is its Name so what then is this name in the brackets? I'm so confused. Need a detailed explanation. Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times previously. Trying to find a duplicate to close this question as now.

Answer (score 0):

You're example shows a resource named `foo` with a property called `name` with the value of `foo`. All resources have a name (defined before the braces), but not all resources have the `name` property (inside the braces).